# Cointegration coefficients using OLS for pairs trading

Tags: multiple-regression, cointegration

[image]

I am trying to model above in excel.

[image]

$$\varepsilon t = \log \operatorname{EURUSD} - \gamma \log \operatorname{GBPJPY} - \mu$$

**Question:** What do I use as $Y$ input and $X$ input for linear regression to find cointegration coefficients (assuming cointegration)?

Also if I was to perform a multiple linear regression on a basket of currency pairs, what would the Y input be in this case?